# Is DES-MAC different from DES-MAC Signature?

Tags: cryptography, signature, javacard, des

I've wrote a simple Javacard applet to calculate signature of an input data using ALG_DES_MAC8_NOPAD signature as below:

```
package testPrj ;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacard.security.*;

public class testPrj extends Applet
{
    private Signature sig8;
    private DESKey key8;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
    {
        new testPrj();
    }
    
    public testPrj(){
        sig8 = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_DES_MAC8_NOPAD, false);
        key8 = (DESKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES_TRANSIENT_DESELECT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES, false);
        register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        if (selectingApplet())
            return;

        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();

        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
        {
        case (byte)0x00:
            apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
            key8.setKey(buf, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
            sig8.init(key8, Signature.MODE_SIGN, buf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 8), (short)8);
            sig8.sign(buf, (short)(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA + 16), (short)8, buf, (short)0);             
            apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)8);
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }           
    }
}
```

As you see above, this applet supports one APDU command only. First 8 bytes of this command is the DES Key, second 8 bytes are IV and the last 8 bytes are the input data which we want to calculate its signature.

Now, we can calculate Signature of `33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33` using Key = `11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11` and IV = `22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22` as below:

```
// Select Applet
Send: 00 A4 04 00 06 <Applet AID> 00
Recv: 90 00

// Request DES Signature
Send: 00 00 00 00 18 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
Recv: F4 03 79 AB 9E 0E C5 33 90 00  <== DES Signature  + Status Words
```

Ok, now take a look at this picture (from [an online tool](http://des.online-domain-tools.com)):

[image]

As you may notice, the output is equal with the applet's response.

So, I conclude that DES_MAC8 signature is equivalent with DES encryption in CBC mode.

Well, now take a look at this definition about DES-MAC qouted from RFC:

> **6.4.6. DES cipher-block chained checksum (des-mac)**
>
> The DES-MAC checksum is computed by prepending an 8 octet confounder
> to the plaintext, performing a DES CBC-mode encryption on the result
> using the key and an initialization vector of zero, taking the last
> block of the ciphertext, prepending the same confounder and encrypting
> the pair using DES in cipher-block-chaining (CBC) mode using a a
> variant of the key, where the variant is computed by eXclusive-ORing
> the key with the constant F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0. The initialization vector
> should be zero. The resulting checksum is 128 bits (16 octets) long,
> 64 bits of which are redundant. This checksum is tamper-proof and
> collision-proof.

Obviously, this definition is different from what happened in the applet/online-tool. So:

**Quetion: Is DES-MAC different with DES-MAC Signature? Does they have different uses? In the other words, does DES-MAC prove something that DES-MAC Signature can't prove that (or vice-versa)?**

Comment: There are two concepts here. CBC-MAC with DES, that is CBC-MAC is first defined with DES and the DES-MAC as defined in the RFC. CMC-MAC has issues, see in Wikipedia. Do you have a restriction for DES?

Comment: Why is that tagged macos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is simple, the DES-MAC you are quoting is [specific to Kerberos 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3961#section-6.2). It's not a CBC-MAC, although it does seem to use the same CBC mode.